# Core Bluetooth scan not returning all devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I just tried a sample code to find the list of all bluetooth devices that are connected or discoverable.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {


var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var peripheral: CBPeripheral?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)


}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    NSLog("Update state \(central.state)")

    if central.state == .poweredOn {
         centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    NSLog("Peripheral \(peripheral)")
}
```

}

The problem is it simply does not show all bluetooth devices that I can see in the Bluetooth menu in Settings app. Moreover, I can't even see device that is already connected to iPhone. What I am doing wrong?

I would ideally like to see all headphone & microphone accessories, not others. Not sure which serviceUUID values I can use and if there is any standard for those values.

Comment: Core Bluetooth can only discover BLE devices. It can't discover legacy devices such as headsets or hands free devices.